# Objects added to a tablerow don't show up?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add some EditTexts to a TableRow programmatially, yet they don't show up on the screen. If I add the EditTexts directly to the TableLayout it works fine but I do want to have them in one row afterall...

```
public void createPlayers(){
    EditText[] editTextSpieler = new EditText[anzahl_Spieler];
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getActivity());
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    for(int i = 0; i < anzahl_Spieler; i++){
        editTextSpieler[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
        editTextSpieler[i].setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
        tableRow.addView(editTextSpieler[i]);
        editTextSpieler[i].getLayoutParams().width = dWidth/(anzahl_Spieler + 1);
        editTextSpieler[i].setHint("Name");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Solution:

```
layoutparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

specifying MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT with TableRow.LayoutParams did the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this change.

```
editTextSpieler[i].getLayoutParams().width = dWidth/(anzahl_Spieler + 1);
editTextSpieler[i].setHint("Name");
//Move to last line in the loop.
tableRow.addView(editTextSpieler[i]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. Also moving it to the last line like that the layoutparams couldnt be changed.

Comment: Can you check by removing this line 
    editTextSpieler[i].getLayoutParams().width = dWidth/(anzahl_Spieler + 1);

Comment: Nothing appears on the screen.

Comment: That shouldn't cause any problems since it doens't cause any problems either when the objects are added directly to the tablelayout.

Comment: ok. Can you remove `layoutparams`  and put `new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)`  and check?

Comment: Because, TabeRow is the parent layout for EditText.